# ssh keys based authentication

Tags: 12.04, ssh

When I set up SSH with authentication based keys
I realized that the private key was needed for authentication to work
But when I deleted the private key (ID_RSA)
I can still log in without a password.

Here is the output of ssh -vvv
https://pastebin.com/1fiLQrdZ

Comment: `Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa`..not very sure. Seems it's there?

Comment: @SouravGhosh /root/.ssh/id_rsa its my private key. 
the public ends with .pub
Even when i delete my private key, i still can connect to the server. What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to ssh to the other host as root?  Or are you as your own user trying the ssh?  You can also try to generate a new key `ssh-keygen` so they no longer match.

Comment: @Terrance I really don't know why, but in ubuntu 16.04 if i delete the private key , it require password again. 
and in Kali linux , it justs connect automatic.

Comment: debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x562f13324250), agent
Do you have ssh agent that may happen to cache keys?

Comment: @vidarlo I don't remember i used ssh-agent. but maybe it started automatic on kali linux.

Answer (score 0):

After you delete your private key,
you can still login without password if you use a key manager that has your private key cached.

After the key manager is stopped,
you will not be able to login with your nonexistent key.
(For example after you logout and login again.)